# Error while starting the application using jetty

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I used the maven plugin "wagon-maven-plugin" to create a single jar which contains the war file and jar files. 
When i try to do `"java -jar myApp.jar"`

I get the following error

```
WARN [main] log.warn(50) | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},file:/Users/hrastogi/chatplus_code_new/chatplus_server/feed-monitor/jetty-pkg/target/feedmonitorservice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jetty-pkg/target/work/webapp/LICENSE (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.JarResource.copyTo(JarResource.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at bekkopen.jetty.Main.start(Main.java:99)
    at bekkopen.jetty.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

The License file is present in the folder.

Any pointer will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that /jetty-pkg/target/work/webapp/LICENSE is the correct absolute path to the file?

Comment: And how are you using the wagon plugin to generate a jar file? It feels like you left something out in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before.
Make sure your JAR file does not contain files with the same name but different case. This is valid inside a JAR file, but not when you expand it in windows. Jetty complains with that kind of deceiving error.

I used maven-shade-plugin to create a big JAR that includes a lot of libraries with a LICENCE file in some of them and a licence folder in others (windows doesn't allow that). See the image

[image: Notice those "lincese" and "LICENSE" files]

Now, if I run this jar. Jetty tries to unpack the content in the windows temp folder and fails with an error similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

As monzonj said. I had the same problem under OS X, which is also case insensitive. The workaround was to configure the packaging maven plugin (the shade plugin, in my case) to skip that file. See my blog post [Fixed: Embedded Jetty Fails To Unpack With FileNotFoundException: Not a directory](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/fixed-embedded-jetty-fails-to-unpack-with-filenotfoundexception-not-a-directory/) describing it.